# How to say "Why I started studying Japanese"

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, particle-が, relative-clauses

I have a Japanese assignment that requires me to write about anything I want. I decided that I wanted to write about why I want to learn Japanese. I think the title should be "Why I want to study Japanese"; would 私は日本語を勉強したい理由 work? I am not sure if I am using 理由 correctly here.

Answer (score 11):

> 「私**は**日本語を勉強したい理由」

This is a nice try, but the 「は」 needs to be replaced by a 「が」.  「は」 is not an option here.  Why not?

That is because 「私**が**日本語を勉強したい」 is a relative clause that modifies 「理由」, correct?

**Inside if-clauses and relative clauses, the subject/topic marker is always 「が」**.

We say:

「ジョーンズさん**が**買った車はBMWです。」

「あなた**が**日本に行くなら、私もいっしょに行きたい。」

The 「が」 in either sentence cannot be replaced by a 「は」.  I might even add that this particular  mistake in the particle choice sounds more serious to us native speakers than you might think.

Finally, you are using 「理由」 correctly.

Comment: Despite sounding a serious mistake, would it be understood?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be though it might take some people a second to understand.  How quickly it is understood would depend mostly on how much experience one has had with foreigners.